# Does any logarithmic function decreases faster than increases?

Tags: functions, proof-writing, logarithms

I am trying to prove the following:

$$\log_2\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(x-a)}\right)>\log_2\left(\frac{f(x+a)}{f(x)}\right).$$

Is the above true for any positive $f(x), f(x+a)$ and $f(x-a)$?

Comment: Use the fact that $\log\frac ab=-\log\frac ba$

Comment: There is no need for the logarithms, you can remove them (logarithm of positive numbers preserves order)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Just take values where it is or is not true.  $\log_2 16 \not > \log_2 32$ so this isn't true if $f(x) = 16f(x-a)$ and $f(x+a) = 32f(x)$ so just pick a function where $f(x-a)=1;f(x) = 16$ and $f(x+a) = 16*32$ for example.  Whereas for an $f(x-a)=1;f(x)=32;f(x+a)=16*32$ it would be true.  Or did you mean to ask if there was any positive function where this is true for every $x,x-a,x+a$?

Answer (score 0):

Since the logarithm is strictly increasing, this inequality is equivalent to

$$\frac{f(x)}{f(x-a)}>\frac{f(x+a)}{f(x)} \quad \iff \quad f(x)^2 >f(x+a)f(x-a)$$

and this is of course not true for all positive $f$ (just take $f\equiv 1$ for example).

Comment: Even more, because functions can be almost arbitrary, you can pick all three values independently for some $x$ and $a$, so you can always choose a triple which violates the inequality.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "always"?

Comment: For example: for every pair of f(x+a) and f(x-a), you can simply compute $\sqrt{f(x+a)f(x-a)}$ and pick something bigger for $f(x)$. The original question does not even concern what the function is doing at other points, just mentions $f(x)$, $f(x-a)$ and $f(x+a)$, so you might as well call them something else and write $A^2>BC$. For every pair of $B$ and $C$, there are infinitely many choices of $0<A\leq \sqrt{BC}$ that violate it.

Comment: Yes, that's obvious, but that is not what I meant. Your comment sounds like you wanted to say that for any **given** function $f$ you can pick $x$ and $a$ such that this property is violated. However, this is trivial as well, if $a=0$ is allowed. I just didn't think about it at all and wanted to know what you had in mind. ;-)